# OpenERP Function Many2One with two values (like Value1 | Value2)

Tags: function, field, odoo

Since Many2one field only displays one field, I thought about wrote a function to display in Many2one two fields, like this way:

```
def get_services(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        values = cr.execute("""SELECT name, entity
                            FROM services WHERE id = 3""")
        values.fetchall()
        for value__ in values:
            if value__:
                return {'value': {'service_id': value__[0] + " | " + value__[1]},} # Example: "Service 1 | Google"
```

First of all, is it possible? Is there any module which does this? So I could see it.

Then, I call the function this way:

```
_columns = {
        'service_id':fields.function(get_services, type = 'many2one', obj = 'services_getservices_function', method = True, string = 'Service'),
```

I'm not getting any error, but the field doesn't display on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is overwriting `name_get` on service model.

see https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.name_get

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I created another field which would contain the name plus the entity.

```
'name_plus_entity':fields.char('All', size = 300),
```

Then I created a function "onchange", so whenever the field 'name' OR the field 'entity' was changed, the field 'name_plus_entity' would get: 'name' + " | " + entity.

Also, I hide the field 'name_plus_entity' in the form XML.